# Event trigger on property change

Tags: c#, reflection, analysis

I am trying to write an analysis tool that compares and tracks data over time in your application.

My goal currently is to find a way to send a trigger to a manager, once the value of a *tracked property* changes.

This process of setting up tracked properties should be as simple as possible, in an ideal world without the need of changes on the actual property code-wise, like the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. **Any** property with a valid getter&setter should be trackable.

My idea was to use Reflection to hook into the setter method of the property, and add a callback there once the setter is called.

Is there a better way to go about this? Or can reflection manage this, and if yes, how?

Comment: You can't do this with reflection unless you actually rewrite the v-table or subclass the type and override a virtual property - I don't recommend those things. Maybe AOP weaving is a better option for you? That would allow you to add the *functionality* without adding the *code noise*?

Comment: You could make all properties raise change notifications by using [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to inject code that raises the `PropertyChanged` event at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

If triggers should be sent as soon as possible on every change, the only option is to add wrappers around properties (one way or the other). AOP frameworks can significantly simplify this and help to avoid boilerplate code (e.g. INotifyPropertyChanged "pattern"). There are a few of them each with its pros and cons, for example:

- PostSharp
- AspectInjector (an example of what may be helpful for your needs
  https://github.com/pamidur/aspect-injector/tree/master/samples/NotifyPropertyChanged)

Comment: I'll take a look into AOP weaving, I'll come back to your answer when I have results!